# Java threads appear to be running more than once

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone explain the following behavior to me?
Given this code:

```
for(int j = 0; j<100; j+=10) {
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new RunAmounts(i+j));
        threads[i].start();
    }
    for(Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            if(thread != null)
                thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
    System.gc();
}
```

Assuming that RunAmounts does nothing but print its parameter.  One would expect a single print of each number 0-99, but each number ends up printing several times. Can someone explain this property of threads?

EDIT: may be due to run(), in actuality, code passes a unique pageNum to RunAmounts which appends it to a SQL statement

```
class RunAmounts extends Thread {

private int pageNum;

public RunAmounts(int pageNum) {
    this.pageNum = pageNum;
}

public void run() {

    ResultSet rs = null;
    String usdAmt, row[] = new String[5], extr[] = new String[3];
    LinkedList<String[]> toWrite = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    CSVWriter fw = null;
    boolean cont;

    try {
        fw = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("Amounts.csv", true), ',');

        do {
            //executes SQL command, initializes rs & pst
            cont = pst.execute();

            while(rs.next()) {  

                //does a bit of parsing

                toWrite.addFirst(row);
                synchronized(this) {
                    fw.writeAll(toWrite);
                    fw.flush();
                }
                toWrite.clear();
            }
            System.out.println("page: " + Integer.toString(pageNum));

            rs.close();

        } while(cont);
        fw.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Comment: @Sot there is no 1 + 9

Comment: post your `run()` of `RunAmount`

Comment: Assuming that `RunAmount` really does just print its parameter, your code works for me: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/0f283c7a2ee9765b2a52

Comment: you sure its `extends Thread`, it should be `implements Runnable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example was hard for me to read, it takes some careful reading to see it's only calling join on the most recent 10 threads started. The array can be gotten rid of (unless you want to hold onto a reference to these in order to call interrupt on them, in which case you need a bigger array, of course), the equivalent functionality in Groovy can be written like this:

```
class RunAmounts implements Runnable {
    final int i
    public void run() {
        println i
    }
    RunAmounts(int i) {this.i = i}
}

def foo() {
    (0 .. 90).step(10).each { j ->
        (0 .. 9).each { i ->
            t = new Thread(new RunAmounts(i + j) as Runnable)
            t.start()
            t.join()
        }
    }
}
```

and it works fine. I can add the array part back in (using a list here but it's the same concept)

```
def foo() {
    (0 .. 90).step(10).each { j ->
        threads = []        
        (0 .. 9).each { i ->
            t = new Thread(new RunAmounts(i + j) as Runnable)
            t.start()
            threads << t
        }
        threads.each { it.join() }        
    }
}
```

and it still works.

So I think you're looking in the wrong spot. Either you edited out the real issue when you created this example or your problem is somewhere else.

How you get the database connection for your RunAmounts object is redacted from your example. JDBC objects are not threadsafe (connections are technically threadsafe though in a way that's not helpful to the application developer, as a practical matter their use needs to be confined to a single thread at a time), if you do this part wrong it could be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I hastily deleted most of the code to try to simplify it and ended up making it fairly confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion would be valid if you remove the first inner loop,

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
for(int j = 0; j<threads.length; j++) {
  //for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    threads[j] = new Thread(new RunAmounts(j));
    threads[j].start();
  // }
}
for(Thread thread : threads) {
    try {
        if(thread != null)
            thread.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: With my code 0-99 should still be the result, perhaps not in that order, but instead of printing 100 values it prints about 1000

Comment: Are you certain there isn't another loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the manual you would recognize that I'm telling you line 3 has probably a problem with the addition.

Whereas

```
/* thread 1 */
t1 = new Date().getTime();

/* thread 2 */
t2 = new Date().getTime();

if(t2 < t1){
  System.out.println("Your wrong with your assumption");
}
```

Wouldn't fit if precision wouldn't have problems.

docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

Use atomic operations in order to ensure memory barriers.

It doesn't matter that's why I'm telling you.

Your assumption of timing is probably wrong:

t2 - t1 > 0

Answer (score 0):

I did some thoughts about timing and everything with more than one t variable sounds like madness. Your problem is rather fundamental of computation and synchronization.

I'd like you to refer to a blog post I've written:
http://sourceforge.net/p/ags/blog/2014/07/mathematical-properties-of-timing/

I do thread synchronization on my system and it's really unreliable and expiring unexpected crashes.